# ajax not communicating with php file

Tags: php, ajax

I'm still learning ajax and I'm trying to get my php file to communicate with the ajax file but I can't get it to work. I might be overlooking something but this is the code:

global.js file:

```
$('input#testbutton').on('click', function() {
   var id = $('[name="selectedPatient"]').val();
   $.post('ajax/selection.php', {id: id}, function(data) {
       alert(data);
   });  
});
```

my selection.php file just echo's "15", but when I press the testbutton, i get no alert. I tested if the button works without the $.post function, by just alerting with an on.click and that works just fine. The var id also works ( alert tested that aswell ).

selection.php :

```
<?php 
   echo "test";
?>
```

Comment: Check Web Developer Tools in your browser, and see what's the error. Plus, choose `console.log` over `alert`.

Comment: i did and nothing shows up on there either

Comment: Syntactically, your code seems fine. So the console should definitely show something. Are you not able to even see the ajax call being made in the console?

Comment: @Styphon He has already mentioned that the click event is working

Comment: @asprin ah yes, I missed that bit.

Comment: Could you show the code of your php file and also check the network tab of your developer console.

Comment: I updated the question with the php file, its just a simple echo the network tool doesn't show any problems

Comment: One more thing - Are you opening the file through `file:\\ ` (double clicking the html file)? If so, try opening it through localhost

Comment: global.js and ajax/selection.php should be in the same folder it should work

Comment: I'm using xamp, localhost to do this...

Comment: Ok, what about my other question `Are you not able to even see the ajax call being made in the console?`

Comment: when i press it the firebug console shows  `POST ajax/selection.php` for one second then its empty again. I will try putting them in the same folder now.

Comment: Putting them in the same folder doesn't change anything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when i press it the firebug console shows POST ajax/selection.php for one second then its empty again –

Aaaah, the page gets reloaded. You should listen to the `submit` event of the `<form>`, and be sure to call `event.preventDefault()` inside the handler.

**HTML:**

```
<form action="ajax/selection.php" method="post" id="yourForm">
  <input name="selectedPatient" type="text">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#yourForm').submit(function(event){

  // this prevents the page from being reloaded
  event.preventDefault();

  $.post(
    $(this).attr('action'), // gets action from the form itself
    $(this).serialize() // serializes the whole form
  ).done(function(data){ // do your business here });

});
```